# Count occurrences based on Multiple Factors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame with over 250 columns. The majority of them are increments of `coil_#` or `register_#` and have a combination of `src` and `dst`. I want to count for each combination of `src` & `dst` count how many times at least one `1` shows in that row. While also counting if it was either a `register` or a `coil`.

Sample Data Frame:

```
srcmacaddr          dstmacaddr         coil_0   coil_1  coil_2  register_0 register_1 register_2
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0        1       0       0           NaN       0       
22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   0        1       0       0           1         1       
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN         NaN       NaN       
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0        0       0       0           0         0       
22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   1        1       1       1           1         1
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   NaN      NaN     NaN     1           1         1
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   0        0       0       0           0         0
```

Sample Desired Output:

```
srcmacaddr          dstmacaddr         Coil or Reg    Coil   Reg
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   1              1      0
22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   2              2      2
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   1              0      1
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0              0      0
```

Edit:

Sample Desired Output (Counting 0's):

```
srcmacaddr          dstmacaddr         Coil or Reg    Coil   Reg
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0              0      0
22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   0              0      0
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   0              0      0
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0              0      0
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   1              1      1
```

Sample Desired Output (Counting 1's or 0's):

```
srcmacaddr          dstmacaddr         Coil or Reg    Coil   Reg
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   1              1      1
22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   2              2      2
00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   1              0      1
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h   0              0      0
00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a   00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d   1              1      1
```

Comment: how did `22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h` become 2, 2,2. I only see one for coil and two for register.

Comment: I just checked. Its 2,2,2 for ```22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` by first 2 columns and then aggregate `max` by columns names before first `_` and then add column filled by random values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['srcmacaddr','dstmacaddr'], sort=False).sum().astype(int)
df1 = df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).max()

m = np.random.randint(2, size=len(df1)) == 1
df1.insert(0, 'Coil or Reg', np.where(m, df1['coil'], df1['register']))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
          srcmacaddr         dstmacaddr  Coil or Reg  coil  register
0  00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d  22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h            0     1         0
1  22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h  00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d            2     2         2
2  00-11-2a-3b-4c-5d  00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a            1     0         1
3  00-99-5d-4c-3b-2a  22-33-6e-7f-8g-9h            0     0         0
```

Comment: Is there a way to bounce between 1,0 or 1 & 0 populated in the row? @jezrael

Comment: @jezraelI - I have edited my question to give an example.

Comment: Can I ask you a couple of questions in a chat?

Comment: I can not find your email.

Comment: Sent you an email, let me know if you received it.

Comment: @BessWiley - Email was sent now.